# socket connect() being mistaken for QT connect()

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I'm trying to create a socket connection from my QT application to a server(regular socket, not a QTcpSocket), to receive data from the server.
The problem is, the `connect` method, upon compilation, gives an error, and points me in the direction of the QT connect method for connecting signals to slots.
How do I tell the compiler to ignore the signal and slot function of QT and find the original socket.h connect function instead?

Comment: Which socket are you using ? there is no class only named socket in Qt. Is it an QAbstractSocket ?

Comment: Its not a QT class, its a system function included in `sys/types.h`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should write

```
::connect(...);
```

To use the proper function. This ensures that resolution occurs from the global namespace.